Changing coordinates with a condition
I have 500x500 grid and random coordinates on this grid. I'm trying to get new random coordinates but they shouldn't be too close to the previous ones. I'm come up with this: In an infinite loop I assign a new random value to a variable and if this value satisfies the condition (it's bigger or smaller on a certain quantity (which may change)) then I'm breaking the loop.
int oldX = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
int oldY = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
int newX;
int newY;
int minDistance = 10;

while (true) {
    newX = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
    if (newX <= (oldX - minDistance) | newX >= (oldX + minDistance)) {
        break;
    }
}

while (true) {
    newY = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
    if (newY <= (oldY - minDistance) | newY >= (oldY + minDistance)) {
        break;
    }
}

But it feels to me not right somehow. Maybe there's a better solution?

I think your question is more appropriate for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Just to remove the repetitious while loop code blocks into a method call instead and, assuming the 500 x 500 grid starts at index 0 and ends at index 499 which would make the current random formula correct as those values are reachable. If 500 is to be inclusive then the current random formula is incorrect as that value is not reachable. You would have to change 500 to 501 to make 500 inclusive.
This also assumes that newX and newY will eventually become oldX and oldY respectively.
int x = 0, y = 0;
int minDistance = 10;
x = getRandom(x, minDistance);
y = getRandom(y, minDistance);
    
System.out.println(String.format("%-3d - %-3d", x, y));   // Optional

The getRandom() Method:
public static int getRandom(int currentXorY, int minDistance) {
    int rnd = currentXorY;
    while (rnd >= (currentXorY - minDistance) && rnd <= (currentXorY + minDistance)) {
        rnd = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
    }
    return rnd;
}


This is much better. Grid is from 0 to 499. I was wondering how to put a condition into the loop itself instead of a if test (shame), now i see. I haven't mentioned that oldX and newX variables need to coexist for a while before newX replaces oldX, but i can handle it :) Thanks a lot man.

It was my pleasure ;)
